# Image resizing - file size not shrinking like in Python

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I just wrote a simple image resizer in Python 2.7 using the PIL environment. Because I wanted a nice and fast GUI, I decided to port it to C#. My Python code looks like this

```
k = I.open(f)
h = int(k.size[1] / float(k.size[0]) * maxWidth)
s = (maxWidth, h) if maxWidth < k.size[0] else k.size #only care about landscape
k = k.resize(s, I.ANTIALIAS)
k.save(os.path.join(outdir, i))
```

whilst my C# port looks like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image, w, h); //image = Image.FromFile()
bitmap.Save(destPath);  //disposing later in the code
```

I'm running into some strange file size problems. With Python I'm resizing the image to about 1500x1000 pixels and the file is about 180kB big. The file created by my C# application at 1500x1000 pixels is about 2000kB big, so I guess there's some unneccessary information added by C#.

How can I reduce my image's file size in C# like I can in Python?

Comment: Setting the quality does the trick. If you might answer the question with the link, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of image, you can set additional properties. Jpeg for instance has a "quality" setting, you can specify while saving the image. See for example msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that these `EncoderParameters` differ per file format. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882589(v=vs.110).aspx to determine which parameters are supported per format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving it in a different format.

```
bitmap.Save("C:\temp",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: In addition to saving as JPEG, you can specify the JPEG quality.

Comment: Is Jpeg a different format from <unspecified in question>?

Comment: I have no idea what the <unspecified in question> format is for python or the c# code, I would assume its .bmp. It was only something for the OP to try and I would have put it in a comment if I had more reputation.